# How do i add a foreign key to link cityid in both the tables?

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
Hotel(hotelid,cityid,hotelname)
city(cityid,cityname)
```

There are two tables 'hotel' and 'city'
How do i link cityid in both tables using phpmyadmin so that whenever i make changes to city table the changes get reflected to hotel table?

Comment: What changes do you plan to make? Once a new city is entered, you shouldn't change the cityid, like, ever, and unless the city is renamed you wouldn't edit cityname, either (and then it's the subject of debate whether you would edit it or add a new entry). So I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to change here.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to insert new data, just insert to both tables.